# react native blur not working over react native camera in Android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm using react-native-blur with Modal to create a blurred background. Everything seems to be working fine in Ios but the blur is not getting applied over when there is a camera preview in the background in Android

[image: Ios]

[image: In Android]

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
  blurStyles: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0
  }
})

export default function BlurredModal({ children, modalProps, blurProps }) {
  return (
    <Modal
      animationType={'fade'}
      transparent={true}
      customStyle={styles.modalStyle}
      {...modalProps}
      radius={14}
      downsampling={2}
      brightness={-200}
      blurStyle='dark'
    >
      <BlurView
        blurAmount={100}
        blurType={'light'}
        style={styles.blurStyles}
        blurRadius={25}
        downsampleFactor={25}
        {...blurProps}
      />
      {children}
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Comment: `Modal` tag did not close in your JSX.

Comment: Yes, Sorry it's my mistake, I have missed it when copying the source code

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @denistepp no, it was an bug from the library and never found the solution for it. But I haven't checked any fixes recently.

Comment: I'm also currently trying it and I found out that on Android, Camera is not recognised as a separate View. If you toggle inspector during the run you will see that on iOS, Camera is inside some kind of wrapper, but not on Android. Maybe that is why the blur is not working...

Comment: could be possible, I stopped searching for a solution it and temporarily at that time I used a condition to unmount the camera component with a view to make the blur work

Comment: please can you help me if any one success with blur camera???

i want something like this 

https://apkpure.com/auto-blur-background-automatically-dslr-camera/com.blurphotos.autoblur.photo.blurimage.dslrautoblurbackground#com.blurphotos.autoblur.photo.blurimage.dslrautoblurbackground-1